# Identificar sistema operativo en bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Me gustaría saber como puedo asignar a una variable el tipo de sistema operativo en el cual se está ejecutando el script.

Seria para diferenciar entre sistemas basados en Debian (apt-get) y basados en Arch (pacman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas, pero vamos por una de ellas.

```
#!/bin/bash
command=$(lsb_release -d)
echo $command
```

Creamos un script de bash, con el comando `lsb_release -d`. al ejecutarlo nos muestra como resultado `Description: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling`, la cual corresponde a mi distro, de igual manera puedes invocar el comando directamente en la terminal y obtendrás el mismo resultado. además tienes la opción de `lsb_release -a` que muestra información mas completa, al igual que `cat /etc/os-release`. importante no olvidar otorgar permisos de ejecución al script para que funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios comandos para confirmar eso, que son propios de ciertas distribuciones, por lo que en otras puede que no te aparezcan esos comandos.

Por ejemplo, en la respuesta aceptada de @sysbot, el comando `lsb_release` me parece que sólo esta disponible para distros basadas en Debian. En tu pregunta dijiste que también lo necesitas para Arch, pero en general, algunas basadas en Red Hat o SUSE, no tendrán ese comando.

También cada distribución puede tener sus propios archivos "lsb-release", "os-release", "redhat-release", etc. Por lo que puedes agrupar todos en un glob y usar `cat`:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /etc/lsb-release
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   2   │ DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
   3   │ DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
   4   │ DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /etc/os-release
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ NAME="Ubuntu"
   2   │ VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
   3   │ ID=ubuntu
   4   │ ID_LIKE=debian
   5   │ PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
   6   │ VERSION_ID="20.04"
   7   │ HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
   8   │ SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
   9   │ BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
  10   │ PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
  11   │ VERSION_CODENAME=focal
  12   │ UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Ya sabiendo esto, al menos en este caso, haciendo un `source /etc/os-release`, tendrías el nombre de la distrubución en la variable `$NAME`.

Pero NO es aplicable a todas las distribuciones.